# How does Cooper pair move in a lattice according to BCS

Tags: superconductivity

According to BCS theory, the cooper pairs have opposite momenta, but according to this animation http://www.superconductors.org/bcs_anim.GIF the electrons in the pair seem to move in the same direction. 
Arent the two information contradicting each other?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: It seems the animation tries to explain how an effective attractive interaction between electrons can arise from electron-phonon interaction, but the depiction of a bound pair moving together is deceiving. In fact, the size of the Cooper pair wavefunction can be quite large. As for the pair shown to having a nonzero net momentum, maybe the intention was to depict a Cooper pair current flowing. This old question may be relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145705